# Access post meta in future_to_publish function

Tags: customization, functions, post-meta

Why am I having trouble accessing post meta data in a future_to_publish add action in functions.php?

I have tried:

```
function post_to_twitter() {
    global $post;
    $url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'short_url', true);
    if(!isset($url) || $url == "") $url = get_permalink($post->ID);
    //post to Twitter code
}
add_action('future_to_publish', 'post_to_twitter', 5);
```

I have also tried:

```
function post_to_twitter($post) {
    $url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'short_url', true);
    if(!isset($url) || $url == "") $url = get_permalink($post->ID);
    //post to Twitter code
}
add_action('future_to_publish', 'post_to_twitter', 5, 1);
```

The post to Twitter code is working just fine, and the function is being called when a scheduled post is published. The code above is trying to get a post meta value "short_url", but it doesn't seem to be working. I believe it has something to do with the $post variable. The exact same code is working perfectly for a "publish_post" function. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @epaps - Where does `'future_to_publish'` come from?  Where is the `doaction('future_to_publish');` called?  I don't find it in WordPress anywhere...

Comment: Why are you setting priority to 5?

Comment: No reason in particular -- just to make sure that it's called early.

Answer (score 1):

Hi **@epaps:**

So I tested your code and it all works fine. The `$post` is passed in as an object and you have full access to the `$post->ID` variable.  Best I can tell is that you have some kind of plugin interaction that is causing it to fail or that, for some reason the scheduled task is not being called *(but if the future post is indeed being published then the latter potential does not seem possible.)*

Hmm, without your full code to debug I'm stumped.  If you come up with me information maybe I can help you find it.

P.S. Here was my first answer which was clearly wrong: *Could it be that you meant to use the `'publish_future_post'` hook instead of `'future_to_publish'`?*

Comment: Mike, take a look at this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions

The function IS being called though, so I'm not sure if "future_to_publish" is the problem or not -- I'm thinking that it has more to do with what's inside the function. Have you seen "publish_future_post" used over "future_to_publish"?

Do you think that either of those code snippets should work?

Comment: @epaps - Ah, you are right. I searched the code for it and couldn't find it and that's because it's composed at runtime. Let me look at it closer...

Comment: I appreciate the help, Mike.

Comment: I think that a combination of using "publish_future_post" and using $post_ID instead of $post->ID may have solved the problem. I'll let you know if it ends up working.